# How to fix CORS error on WebView Chrome 76?

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, chrome76

I've sent request from my app to API server; on WebView Chrome 76.0.3809.89 API cannot be called
The following error is shown on the log:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://.....' from origin 'file://' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

It works normally on Chrome 75.
How can I disable this CORS checking on WebView Android? Or is there any other solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be the bug of Chrome 76
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107
Close app and run again then it worked again.

**UPDATE**: Chrome 76.0.3809.111 (rolled out to 100% user) fixed the problem; now just update chrome to fix.

Comment: We have absolutely same issue, and if I close the app, it works, but as we have B2C app this is not really the solution. Please if you find better solution, post it here. I will do the same :)

Comment: @hyperN: From this link: WebView 76 seems to take a wrong configuration only at the first launch time --> If we need to update the app, we also need to close it; why we need that update if close and open again work as expected? :D Maybe you need something non-technical solution such as publish a notification to user or email to them.

Comment: I have noticed issues on a specific client site, is a SPA application that works nicely when first open, but if the client tries to reload it will get stuck on API calls and others call for mixpanel for instance, it will work only if chrome is closed and reopen or trying to open on incognito window

Comment: We are still seeing this error occurring on some devices running 76.0.3809.111

Comment: @RichardShergold I think you should try to clear app data in those devices and run app again.

Comment: @o0omycomputero0o yes - killing the app and re-starting it solves the issue but its not really very easy for us to ask thousands of users to do that

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with chrome version 76.0.3809.89, (I was using a hybrid app)
[image: cors erro]
although when I closed that app totally(it shouldn't be working in the background) and then tried again it worked.

To fix this issue you must upgrade your chrome to 76.0.3809.111. That worked for me, then it also worked for the first time without having to close the app.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the same issue that is chrome webview 76 issue, which is an update from 1st of Aug 2019, after that day we got this issue, that is a bug in chrome if you pass header value in ajax request in your hybrid apps then you got this issue. Now their team has rolled out

Below is the chromium update...

"The behavior in WebView should be the same regardless of whether it's being provided by Chrome or by the separate WebView package, and the update with the fix is being rolled out to both Chrome and WebView simultaneously. It's currently being released to 10% of users and will be incrementally rolled out to everyone if we don't see any new issues. So if you see one being updated and not the other that's just because it's an incremental rollout - the two packages are updated independently here so a given device can get one updated before the other. There's nothing to worry about and you should not advise users to switch implementation; just wait until 76.0.3809.111 is rolled out to all users."

more : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107